# If I exchange the CPU, must I reinstall the OSes? (swapping cpus from one *nix-like to another)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, cpu, freebsd

as suggested by the title, I want to change CPU: actually I have two computers, one with Ubuntu running on an AMD Athlon 64 dual core 5200+ and the other with FreeBSD running on an AMD Sempron single core LE-1250.

I would like to swap (I am not sure that this is the correct term...) the CPUs from one computer to the other one, that is take the dual core from the ubuntu pc and put it inside the freebsd pc and viceversa. The mobo is the same.

Do you think I will encounter problems?

Comment: I have "dual-cored" the FreeBSD machine, and it's running smoothly...for the other machine I have to wait: the PSU is melted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine, at least on the Ubuntu side (I don't use freebsd often, so my opinion there is worthless), as long as you're not moving from 32bit to 64bit (and it might work then, but I've never tried it).

Linux is amazingly hardy as far as switching hardware goes: I love taking a hard drive out of a dead machine, slapping it into the nearest available machine, and booting it up. If you can do it with a die-hard Windows guy present, it's a beautiful thing: the boot throws about a hundred errors...Then boots right up.

Comment: It seems that both CPUs could operate in 32 and 64 bit: better chance to succeed? EDIT:oh, and thanks a lot for the infos!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the word size is compatible, the most you'd have to do is put a SMP kernel in place for the multicore CPU, assuming the original kernel was UP.